# How can I load a .ttf font file for a Tkinter label?

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I want to make a old-fashioned rocket blastoff game.

But, I want to use the Windows CMD font for the text I will put on the screen.

I have the font here:
https://www.dafont.com/windows-command-prompt.font

Now I need to write the code.

How can I load the font into Tkinter and put it on a Label?

Comment: Install the font and you can use it in your tkinter application.

Comment: Not very helpful. __How__ do I do that?